# function renders previous values after updation in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-night-tln1w?file=/src/App.js

the data in dropdown after being updated shows the correct values in console, however in the dropdown it shows the previous values,
If updated again, the last values consoled are updated in the dropdown. Maybe some error due to `await`

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example in your question.

Comment: @DrewReese please check

Comment: Why you using `await` on every function? It doesn't make sense

Comment: Please edit your question and insert a **runnable code** without referring to an external file

Answer (score 1):

`setState` method does not return a promise, so it cannot be awaited. Instead, you should use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method to know when your state was updated.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` [is updates the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#:%7E:text=setState()%20does%20not%20always%20immediately%20update%20the%20component) `asynchronously` even if you use `await` becuse it does not return a promise. To get the updated state immediately after `setState` use callback in `setState`.

```
 handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    this.setState({
      csvfile: event.target.files[0]
    }, async (newState) => { // New State will here
       await this.importCSV();
   });
  };
```

```
  displayKeys = async (data) => {
    await this.setState({ keys: [] });
    const arry = this.state.arr
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data[0])) {
      arry.push(key);
    }
    this.setState({ arr })
  };
```

Comment: `display` is giving correct output in console. Tried this as well, but `arr` doesn't get updated

Comment: `this.state.arr.push(key)` this does not update the state, you should use `setState` to update the state